# webview setBackgroundColor when play gif image

Tags: android, webview, gif

i want to play gif use web view,default webview  background is white.so i use :

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

but when i use the above code,my gif can play,but behind of my gif it also draw one pic of gif
as:

[image]

In the pic you will see a redundant pic at the behind. My original gif pic is like this:

[image: original gif]

When I was trying to delete `webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)`, the gif was showing good, but background was white.

When i add the code, my gif always have a a redundant pic of the gif.

So my question is: how can I set my gif background as transparent but not mess up the gif?